# Ruby select on array of arrays filtering with regex containing variable

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, select

```
examp = [["packed"], ["crud"], ["paced"], ["it"], ["emo"], ["wrote"], ["pcd"], ["ppcd"], ["pcd"]]

word = 'pcd'

foo = examp.select { |a| a[0][/[aeiou#{word}]/] }
p foo
```

Expected output:
    [["paced"], ["pcd"]]

Actual output:

[["packed"], ["crud"], ["paced"], ["it"], ["emo"], ["wrote"], ["pcd"]]

Edit: 
["ppcd"] and ["pcd"] (second time) added to the array.  I forgot to mention that I also want to exclude words that have more than one occurrence of a letter in pcdaeiou, or words that appear more than once.  Sorry.

Edit 2:
The specific problem is I want to filter an array by a given string (of letters) + some other letters.    I don't want the out put to contain words with anything but, in the example, pcdaeiou.  However, duplicates of aeiou are allowed, I just dont want repeated instances of p,c, or d.

Comment: Your question does not explain what you intend to achieve

Comment: I don't even see a question.

Comment: I trust you will approve of the edit I made to your question.  You may wish to edit the question to either confirm that my understanding is correct, or edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` in a regex denotes a character class.  It matches a character that is any of the characters within it.  So it's finding any word that contains a, e, i, o, u, p, c or d.

It's not clear what your really after though... Are you saying that a p, c, and d is required, but also allow vowels, but not any other consonants?  If so, I'd say it's simplest to use two regexes.  One to see if the letters you need are present, and another to make sure it only contains letters you allow.

And for all that is holy... use `=~`

```
examp.select do |a|
  a[0] =~ /#{word}/ && a[0] =~ /^[#{word}aeiou]+$/
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the question is, "Select all arrays `[str]` from `examp` for which all characters of the string `str` are `a, e, i, o or u`, or one of the letters of the value of the variable `word`".

```
examp = [["packed"], ["crud"], ["paced"], ["it"], ["emo"], ["wrote"], ["pcd"]]
word = 'pcd'

p examp.flatten.select {|a| a.chars.all? {|c|
  "aeiou#{word}".include?(c)}}.map {|e| [e]} # => [["paced"], ["pcd"]]
```

Edit: if, in my statement above of the question, each character of `str` "consumes" a matching character of `"aeioupcd"`, then my solution could be modified as follows:

```
examp = [["packed"], ["crud"], ["paced"], ["it"], ["emo"], ["wrote"], ["pcd"], ["ppcd"]]

str = "aeiou#{word}" # => "aeioupcd"
p examp.flatten.select {|a| s = str.dup; a.chars.all? {|c|
  s.delete!(c)}}.map {|e| [e]} # => [["paced"], ["pcd"]]
```

For `a == "ppcd"`, `"aeioupcd"` is seen to contain the first "p" because `"aeioupcd".delete!("p")` returns "p" (rather than nil).  However, `delete!` also removes this character from `"aeioupcd"`, so the second "p" in "ppcd" is evaluated in `"aeioucd".delete!("p") => nil`, so "ppcd" is not selected.

Comment: This is the correct solution except for the case of duplicates, see ppcd edit above.  Thanks