# How do I get the sorting right in my algorithm's output?

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to build a simple algorithm to detect if two or more strings in an array matche a given list of words in a much larger array uniquely, as in, only one appearance of the characters in `g`, AND an unlimited amount of appearances of the vowels `aeiou`.

The consonants in the shorter array should remain in the same order as in the target.

I want to return an Array of Arrays with all the matches to each individual string in their own array:

Examples:

```
target = ["bs", 'tr', 'gl',...] #etc...(Imagine if there were n items in the array, an each array item need not be only 2-chars long.

target2 = ['bs', 'tr', 'bbss']
target3 = ['glw', 'gl', 'bbss']
target4 = ['bstrgl', 'gl', 'bss']

arr = ['base', 'true', 'glow', 'bees', 'bass', 'sabb', 'babss', 'glee', 'basatragl']

q = []


for x in 0..s.length
word = arr.collect{ |z| [z, z.gsub(/[aeiou]/,"")] }.select{ |z| z[1] == s[x]}.collect{|z| z[0]}

q << word
end

p q
```

EDIT:
For target, the expected output is:

```
#=> [['base', 'true', 'glee'], ['bees', 'true', 'glee']]

# for this example, this is the total amount of answers possible given array arr.  

# all others either have more than 1 b or s, or contain other consonants.
```

For target 2:
    ['base', 'true', 'babss'], ['bees', 'true', 'babss']
target3:
    ['glow', 'glee', 'babss']
target4:
    ['basatragl', 'glee', 'bass']

I'm getting this output (for target), but I'm not sure how to get the output sorted more prettily as above:

```
[[\"base"\, \"bees"\], [\"true"\,], [\"glee"\]]
```

I'm not sure where I went wrong. How can I get the output into proper buckets, and also get rid of the \'s?

Comment: This problem, or variants, have appeared on SO several times in recent weeks, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695078/ruby-select-on-array-of-arrays-filtering-with-regex-containing-variable) for example.  Have you done a search?

Comment: looks like an homework, even though this seems a different variant

Comment: I revised my answer after reading your changes.  You will see I also revised my statement of the problem, as I now understand it.  If that is correct, I suggest you edit your question to incorporate it.  As it stands, your question is still not clear, and likely will be removed if you do not fix it.  (It might be removed anyway because you did not fix it earlier.)  Answers you receive are not just for your benefit; they are also to help others who read your question in future.  You owe it to them, and to those who try to help you, to write clear, concise and complete questions.

Comment: I agree, to me it is clear, let me know what is unclear still to you?

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ['base', 'true', 'glow', 'bees', 'bass', 'sabb', 'babss', 'glee', 'basatragl']
target = ["bs", 'tr', 'gl']

arr.each_with_object({}) do |word,hash| 
   if target.include? word.tr("aeiou","")
     hash[word.tr("aeiou","")] ||= []
     hash[word.tr("aeiou","")] << word
   end
 end.values
=> [["base", "bees"], ["true"], ["glee"]]
```

Comment: Doesn't match OP expected output

Comment: @user3125373 except for the escapes there is no difference between the output and the OP's expected output

Comment: [['base', 'true', 'glee'], ['bees', 'true', 'glee']] is the expected output

Comment: @user3125373 your question and expected answer seems to have a conflict "I want to return an array of arrays with all the matches to each individual string in their own array." how does base, true and glee justify this??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work:

```
def doit(arr, target)
 hh = Hash[arr.map {|w| [w, w.tr('aeiou', '')]}]
 ht = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}) \
   {|w, h| h[hh[w]] << w if target.include?(hh[w])}
 a = target.reduce([]) {|ar, s| ar << ht[s]}
 a.first.product(*a[1..-1])
end

arr = %w[base true glow bees bass sabb babss glee basatragl]
  # => ["base", "true", "glow",..., "basatragl"] 

doit(arr, ["bs", 'tr', 'gl'])
  # => [["base", "true", "glee"], ["bees", "true", "glee"]] 
doit(arr, ['bs', 'tr', 'bbss'])
  # => [["base", "true", "babss"], ["bees", "true", "babss"]] 
doit(arr, ['glw', 'gl', 'bbss'])
  # => [["glow", "glee", "babss"]] 
doit(arr, ['bstrgl', 'gl', 'bss'])
  # => [["basatragl", "glee", "bass"]]
```

Let's see what's going on here:

- Creating the hash `hh => {"base"=>"bs", "true"=>"tr",...,"basatragl"=>"bstrgl"}` simplifies the expression that follows.
- `each_with_object` enumerates `arr` with the object being a hash created by the expression `Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}`.  Creating a hash this way makes the default value an empty array.  If `h` is that hash, `h[k] << v` appends `v` to the array `h[k]` if the hash has a key `k`; else `h[k]` is set to `[]` and then `v` is appended, so `h[k] = [v]`.
- For the following, assume `target = ['bs', 'bbss', 'tr']`.
- `ht => {"bs"=>["base", "bees"], "tr"=>["true"], "bbss"=>["babss"]}`.
- `a = target.reduce([]) {|ar, s| ar << ht[s]}` creates and array `a` consisting of the values `ht[k]` of the hash `ht`, with keys `k` as  ordered as in `target`. `a => [["base", "bees"], ["babss"], ["true"]]`.
- `a.first = ["base", "bees"]` and `a[1..-1] = [["babss"], ["true"]]`, so `["base", "bees"].product(*[["babss"], ["true"]]) # => [["base", "babss", "true"], ["bees", "babss", "true"]]`.

You need to be clarify your question.  If you do not, it likely will attract negative votes and eventually be removed.  My understanding is based largely on what you cite as the expected answer.  This is the question I attempted to answer:

Given arrays `arr` and `target`, each containing no duplicate values, construct an array of arrays (each of the latter to be referred to as `asub`) such that:

- each array `asub` is of size `target.size` and is comprised of unique elements of `arr`; and
- if the vowels `a, e, i, o, u` are removed from each element of `asub`, `asub` equals `target`.

Yes, this is a bit of a mouthful, but it is important to be precise.  If you edit your question, free free to incorporate these words or some variant thereof.

Comment: I know, this is a tricky problem, hard to put into words.  Your example works unless the target array has more items in it of varying lengths (ie more than length = 2).  If I put 'bss' into the array for instance, it returns output not in the correct sequence.  Glee will come after bass, which makes me realize there is some alphabetizing that must be occurring against my will ;)

Comment: I will change my solution to meet your requirements if you edit your question to clarify what you want, giving a few examples of input/expected output.

Comment: Thanks, I have done so, let me know if anything is still unclear?